# Error creating Docker container in Bluemix

Tags: docker, containers, ibm-cloud

To create a Docker container in Bluemix we need to install container plug-ins and container extension. After installing container extension Docker should be running but it show error as :

```
    root@oc0608248400 Desktop]# cf ic login
    ** Retrieving client certificates from IBM Containers
    ** Storing client certificates in /root/.ice/certs
    Successfully retrieved client certificates
    ** Checking local docker configuration
    Not OK
    Docker local daemon may not be running. You can still run IBM Containers on the cloud

There are two ways to use the CLI with IBM Containers:

Option 1) This option allows you to use `cf ic` for managing containers on IBM Containers while still using the docker CLI directly to manage your local docker host. 
    Leverage this Cloud Foundry IBM Containers plugin without affecting the local docker environment:


    Example Usage:
    cf ic ps
    cf ic images
Option 2) Leverage the docker CLI directly. In this shell, override local docker environment to connect to IBM Containers by setting these variables, copy and paste the following:

    Notice: only commands with an asterisk(*) are supported within this option


    export DOCKER_HOST=tcp://containers-api.ng.bluemix.net:8443
        export DOCKER_CERT_PATH=/root/.ice/certs
        export DOCKER_TLS_VERIFY=1
    Example Usage:
    docker ps
    docker images
```

exec: "docker": executable file not found in $PATH

Please suggest what should I go next.

Comment: could you edit your question so that it is clear what command(s) you ran, what the output was, ...?

Comment: It looks like your docker is not properly configured. Can you try to run any docker commands? Like 'docker images' or 'docker ps'?

Answer (score 2):

the error is already telling you what to do:

`exec: "docker": executable file not found in $PATH`

means to find the executable `docker`.

Thus the following should tell you where it is located and that would needed to be append to the `PATH` environment variable.

```
dockerpath=$(dirname `find / -name docker -type f -perm /a+x 2>/dev/null`)
export PATH="$PATH:$dockerpath"
```

What this will do is search the root of the filesystem for a file, named 'docker', and has the executable bit set while ignoring error messages and returns the absolute path to the file as $dockerpath. Then it exports this temporarily.

Comment: Another thing to note: *Option 1) This option allows you to use `cf ic` for managing containers on IBM Containers* Is telling you to use IBM's wrapper for docker.

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be that your docker daemon isn't running.

Try running:

```
sudo docker restart
```

If you've just installed docker you may need to reboot your machine first.